# How to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{\ln{n}}(1-a_{n})=1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, roots

let equation $x^n+x=1$ have positive $a_{n}$.

show that
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n}{\ln{n}}(1-a_{n})=1$$

yesteday, I have post this and prove following
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}=1$$
[How prove this limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485032/how-prove-this-limit-displaystyle-lim-n-to-inftya-n-1)

Now I found This beautiful  limtit. Thank you everyone can prove it

Answer (score 4):

Let $a_n=1-\varepsilon$.  Then

$$(1-\varepsilon)^n - \varepsilon=0\implies n = \frac{\log{\varepsilon}}{\log{(1-\varepsilon)}} \sim \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\log{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}} \quad (\varepsilon \to 0)$$

One may show that, in this case, because this limit is equivalent to $n \to \infty$,

$$\varepsilon \sim \frac{\log{n}}{n} \quad (n \to \infty)$$

To see this, note that

$$\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\log{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}\sim \frac{n}{\log{n}} \log{\frac{n}{\log{n}}} = \frac{n}{\log{n}} (\log{n}-\log{\log{n}})\sim n $$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\log{n}} (1-a_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\log{n}} \varepsilon = 1$$

as was to be shown.

Comment: Thank you,But $n\sim\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\log{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}$? How can we prove must $\varepsilon \sim \frac{\log{n}}{n} \quad (n \to \infty)$?

Comment: @math110: this represents a bit of inverse thinking.  The conditions $\varepsilon\to 0$ and $n \to \infty$ are equivalent, so we can "solve" for $n$ as I did in the first line above.  From there, I showed how $\varepsilon$ behave in the third line.

Comment: Why not write $a_n=1-\varepsilon_n$?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: got seduced by the notation in the previous problem.  No real good reason.

Comment: @RonGordon Ah, OK. At first, I thought the argument was another, so maybe it might improve clarity.

Comment: I guess must  $$g(n)<a_{n}<\dfrac{n}{n+1}$$?How find the simple form of $g(n)$.such $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)=1$$

Comment: @math110: I do not understand your question.

Comment: @RonGordon,I have edit,Now understand my question?

Comment: your mean? $$(1-e^{-n^2})^n-e^{-n^2}<0?$$

Comment: @math110: no, I think I may have misunderstood.  Why don't you ask this as a separate question?

Comment: I'm thinking about a simple method and beautiful methods to solve  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=1$$

Comment: @math110: The above asymptotic expression is a good start!