# How to find the real positive root of $x^{k/2} - x - 1$.

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics, roots

Let $k$ be a large even integer.  The following polynomial has exactly one real positive root.

$$x^{k/2} - x - 1$$

How can one determine what it is asymptotic to, as a function of $k$?

Comment: There is in general no closed form of that root.

Comment: A possible approach: (i) For sufficiently large $k$ show the root $x^*(k)$ satisfies $1<x^*(k)<2$; (ii) Find $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} x^*(k)$.

Comment: Three related questions: [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/485032/5531), [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/485341/5531), [three](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/485408/5531).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$f_k(x)
=x^k-x-1
$.

$f_k(0) = -1$,
$f_k(1) = -1$,
and
$f_k(2)
=2^k-3
\gt 0
$
for
$k \gt \log_2(3)
\approx 1.58
$.

If
$x = 1+y/k$,
then,
for large $k$,

$\begin{array}\\
f_k(x)
&=(1+y/k)^k-(1+y/k)-1\\
&\approx e^y-2-y/k\\
&=e^y-2-y/k\\
&\approx e^y-2\\
&=0
\qquad\text{for } y = \ln(2)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$f_k(1+\ln(2)/k)
\approx 0$.

As a check,

$\begin{array}\\
f_k(1+\ln(2)/k)
&=(1+\ln(2)/k)^k-(1+\ln(2)/k)-1\\
&\approx 2-2-\ln(2)/k\\
&=O(1/k)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thank you so much.